# Store Weblogic JMS messages for analysis

Tags: java, jms, weblogic, weblogic8.x

We are currently having issues with Weblogic JMS, some of the messages received by the Tibco end are blank, but, our logs indicate that the messages are sent in full (we log just before sending it to the queue). We are planning to store the jms messages for a couple of days and verify if that is a problem at the Weblogic end or the tibco end.

I know that there is a persistance store in JMS, but that will clear the messages once the message is sent to the client. Do we have a feature that allows us to store the messages for a period of time?

Environment: Weblogic 8.1 Integration

Thanks.

Comment: Use a Database Persistent Store and then work on the Database Level (maybe using a trigger?) to replicate the JMS data to another table/database.

Answer (score 3):

When using JMS queues for messages, the message is meant for consumption by only 1 consumer. Once the message is consumed its removed from the JMS server for good.

I understand your requirement is to save the already delivered messages for reconciliation. This is not possible out of the box in WLS (for obvious reasons).

You have the following options

1) Enable JMS message logging, this will save all the messages that reach the server to be logged as a text xml in a log file.

2) Use QueueBrowser and read the messages and log it to where ever you want in what ever format you need.

Comment: the Weblogic version (8.1) that I use does not support logging. Does the QueueBrowser code detect the new messages i the queue? or I should read the message every second to find out the messages. I've read up somewhere saying that the QueueBrowser logs only properties, is it true?

Comment: Queue Browser is just like a JMS Queue consumer which will get all the messages from the queue, it gets all parts of the message not just the properties. It will ensure the message is not removed from queue.